# how to split div by 2 sections using border css

Tags: css, border

so i have a div and i already splited it colors with this:

```
.menu-slide-outer  {
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF 23%, transparent 10%);
}
```

so now i need to separate half, or exactly 23% of the div with border, how can i do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXXDn.png) this is painting of what i want (border only needs to be in the top, right, left and separating div )

i cant rly edit an html of the site, so i can use ONLY CSS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taFXM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use even more layers in the gradient! You can resize the block by grabbing the bottom right corner.

```css
.menu-slide-outer {
  /* For example only --> */ height: 180px; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; resize: both;
  
  background: 
    0 0 / 100% 23% linear-gradient(90deg, #000 0 2px, #0000 2px  calc(100% - 2px), #000 calc(100% - 2px)) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(180deg, #000 0 1px, #0000 2px calc(23% - 1px), #000 calc(23% - 1px) calc(23% + 1px), #fff200 calc(23% + 1px), #0000 calc(23% + 1px)),
    linear-gradient(180deg, #ff002b 23%, #fff200 23%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-slide-outer"></div>
```

Comment: yes, but I don't need a border after the dividing line

Comment: @zxczxcxzc121zxcdsafds232: Please clarify the issue. Does the answer not match the image attached in the question?

Comment: see new image i attached